# How to decouple the grounds for two different switching regulators?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ground

I've a single DC 24V battery supply, which I use as the input for generating separate 12V and 5V supplies. Two separate LM2576T ICs are used to regulate the voltage to the lower levels. However, the problem is that I'll be using this to power an STM32 based circuit that drives some relays, the relays being driven by the 12V supply and if the ground for both the 12V and 5V are same then that would defeat the point of using an optocoupler in front of the relays (In fact, for some reason two of the optocouplers on my board got burned which is when I realized that this could be a problem). I want the circuits to be isolated. So the question is, how do I generate two separate ground planes from a single battery supply? Right now both the regulator ICs have the battery negative as the ground.

Comment: I'd be more interested in solving why you had two optocouplers burned firstly.

Comment: If the supplies **only** electrically connect at one point, then they *are* still isolated.  One connection will not allow current to flow.  Current flow requires a complete loop from source to drain - two or more connections - so something else is the likely culprit. Such reference connections are common in all sorts of electronics - a "star" ground might connect Earth, chassis, analog, digital, and RF grounds all at one point, even though they are used for very different things and at very different voltages.  We need to see schematics of what you are doing to be more specific.

Comment: Probably by using an [isolated power supply.](http://application-notes.digchip.com/026/26-20176.pdf) The application notes for the 257X series shows how.

Comment: @sixter Post a schematic